# Python Binary String Loop

Tags: python, loops, binary

The question on my assignment is as follows:

> Write a function that takes, as an argument, a string, identified by the variable `aString`. If the string only contains digits 0 and 1, return the string formed by concatenating the argument with the string "is a binary string." Otherwise, return a string indicating the length of the argument, as specified in the examples that follow. Name this function `AmIBinary(aString)`.

I am having trouble figuring out how to form a loop which searches through a string and determines whether or not the string is a binary string. I understand how to get the length of a string, I just don't understand how to figure out if it is a binary string.

Comment: `re.match("[01]+",test_string)`

Comment: Use a `for` loop.  Something like `for char in aString:`.   You should also take some time to go through the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this !

```
import re
def AmIBinary(aString):
    #test_str='Vijay'
    if re.match("[01]+",aString):
        print('Binary string')
    else:
        print(len(test_str))

#AmIBinary("Vijay")
AmIBinary('010101')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop through a string the same way you can use with a list of numbers.

For example:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

You can use:

```
for number in numbers:
    # Do something
```

In your case, you just need to switch the number list by the string you receive as an argument like this:

```
aString = '100100100'

for number in aString:
    # Check if there's a different number than '0' and '1'
```

Look that in this case you need to compare it with the string version of the number, because you're iterating a string, so each value you receive from the for loop will be a string too.

In the end, you'll probably have something like this:

```
def AmIBinary(aString):
    for number in aString:
        if number != '0' and number != '1':
            return len(aString)
    aString += 'is a binary string'
    return aString
```

As you can see I am iterating through the string to check if any element of it is different than '1' and '0', if it is, I just return the length of the string, otherwise, if I checked every value in the string and everything is fine, I concatenate 'is a binary string' to the original string and return it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: `if number not in '10':` would be a lot more readable/pythonic in my opinion.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you're right, however I think that it's clearer to write this way for someone who is starting and that could use this example for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try the build-in function remix without use loop.

```
def AmIBin(s):
    try:    
       if s.startswith('0b'):
           int(s, 2)
       else:   
           int('0b{}'.format(s), 2)
    except: 
        return False
    else:   
        return True
```

Answer (score -1):

A binary string has been defined as a string that only contains "0" or "1". So, how about checking each 'character' in the string, and if it's not a "0" or "1" you will know that the string is not a binary string.